# Testing if something is a reference to something else

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

Suppose I have:

```
  std::vector<Foo> v1;
  std::vector<Foo> v2;
  std::vector<Foo>& rV = v1;
```

How can I do a test like this:

```
  TEST_EQ(v1, rV);
  TEST_NOT_EQ(v2, rV);
```

I'd image this is a common issue for those of you who unit test your code.

Comment: To see if they're really the same underlying `vector`, you can simply compare their addresses.  (If not, then your test assertions will need to progress to a comparison of elements).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can detect if two objects are the same by comparing their addresses.

```
if (&v1 == &rV)
```

will be true only if they are referring to the same vector.

(assuming of course that you haven't overloaded the address-of operator :-)

Comment: I think this will work as long as the vector isn't changed, such as using pushback. If the vector is changed then the addresses maybe different. Using reserve before a vector operation does somewhat mitigate that.

Comment: That would be true for members of the vector, but we are comparing addresses of the vector object itself. That doesn't change.